# Select leave data from attendance table given the following condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have attendance data for employees stored in the table `attendance` with the following column names:

- **emp_id** (employee ID)
- **date**
- **type** (leave, absent, etc.)

(there are others but I'm omitting them for the sake of simplicity)

My objective is to retrieve all dates of the given month on which the employee was on leave (type = 'Leave') ***and the last leave taken in the last month, if any***.

It's easy to do it using two queries (I'm using PHP to get process the data), but is there any way this can be done in a single query?

Comment: @Isaiah Sure, no rush here. :-) It's just that I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

Comment: I'd combine the two queries with UNION

Comment: My query might be more efficient

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not obvious to me what you want output for the query.  For instance, what is the "given month"?  What is the "last month"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE type="Leave" AND
date <= (CURRENT_DATE() - 30)
```

Select the fields, etc you want then se a combined where clause using mysql's `CURRENT_DATE()` function. I subtracted 30 for 30 days in a month.

If date is a date column, this will return everyone who left 1 month or longer ago.

Edit:

If you want a specific date, change the 2nd month like this:

```
date <= (date_number - 30)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. "Leave" here doesn't mean that the person left the company; it's when the person took the day off. :)

Comment: Well, you can edit the condition, but this is probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question so as to close it. As @bpgergo pointed out in the comments, UNION will do the trick here.